# Wordpress: How to display submenu menu in parent menu

Tags: php, wordpress

I need help for Wordpress 
if parent menu page data is empty in Menu then I want it to display its first sub menu data  in wordpress
please help how this can be done

Comment: you should provide website link or code on which you are putting efforts.

Comment: will not be able to answer this question: it depends on your theme. Some theme use WP inner built menus, some don't and have their own interface and menu objects. Plus, the menu display can be modified in the template. Please add code for menu display, theme name, such infos we need

Comment: I just simply add an test page and its sub menu as abc page and i have add the text to abc page now i want if i open test page it automatically display abc data
 how to do that

Comment: by using Custom Nav Walker. You can customize wp nav menu as per your requirement. https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/Walker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure that you would like my idea or not but I just want to suggest you about the custom links.

**STEP 1**  First need to create a page suppose ABC and then add the content into ABC page.

**STEP 2**  After that go to your appearance menu section and create the custom link, now into the URL tab add the URL of your ABC page like this `http://localhost:808/wp/abc/`   and gave a name to the menu Test

**STEP 3**  Then add the ABC as a submenu of Test custom menu

Thanks